# Typescript find MediaDeviceInfo of rear camera

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mediadevices

I am using the `ZXingScannerComponent` with Angular. With this component you have to set the desired camera based on it's `MediaDeviceInfo`. My current code looks something like that:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(function(devices) {

   for (const device of devices) {
      if (/back|rear|environment/gi.test(device.label)) {
        this.qrScanner.device = device;
        break;
      }
    }

})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
});
```

This code sadly doesn't work on all devices because of the `/back|rear|environment/gi.test(device.label)` condition.

Is there a possibility to get the `MediaDeviceInfo` of a camera with the help of the constraint `{ video: { facingMode: 'environment' }}`?